# Reading an Object from ObjectInputStream without having the class defined

Tags: java, server, client, iostream, classnotfoundexception

I'm programming a Client-Server game in Java and I need to send a class to the server in order to resend the class to another client.

The problem is that the class has other classes as attributes so it's not easy and clean to have all the classes at the server when the only task that the server does is resend the object that recieves.

I've tried by writing, reading and casting (Object) like that:

`Object partida = (Object) ois.readObject();`

The *java.lang.ClassNotFoundException* still appears.

Is there any way to resend the object without having the class defined on the server?

**Client that sends data:**

```
@Override
public void run() {
    while(!isInterrupted()){
        try {

            String missatge = (String) ois.readObject(); //Has a request
            if(missatge.equals("PARTIDA")){
                oos.writeObject(gameWindow.getPartida()); //Sends object of the class Partida
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            break;
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

**Server which has to resend the data**

```
public Object getPartida(){
    Object partida = null;
    try {
        oos.writeObject("PARTIDA"); // send the request
        partida = ois.readObject(); //read the Object --> here is where occurs the exception

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return partida; //this method returns the "Partida" which has to be resend to another client
}
```

Comment: Could you show us more of your code?

Comment: Have you tried using an OO-way with inheritance?

Comment: If you have a serialized object and server is acting as proxy then you can simply redirect the binary stream, there's no need to deserialize  the object first.

Comment: you can just send some representation of the state of the class and the client should construct the class using that state.

Comment: And how would yo do that? @11thdimension

Comment: Since your server only needs to act as a proxy it can simply write the received object binary to the output stream of the client request. Server doesn't need to deserialize this binary stream. Client on the other hand will be able to deserialize after receiving the stream.

Comment: But how can i read from the Input Stream without deserializing? I mean the exception occurs when doing the ois.readObject() so i understand that this method automatically deserialize. Which method should I use? @11thdimension

Comment: :) so when you say that `resend the object that recieves` you don't mean that server has the deserialized object? What does this mean then? Because if you had object itself then you would have classes too.

Comment: I'll try to explain it better. What I need is a Server which acts like a "bridge" between one client and another. The first client will send and object from a class defined in the client but not in the server. So what I need is to send this data to the server and the server resend this data (without deserializing it) to the other client which will deserialize and use the data properly.  Is it clear now? if there is something i'm not explaining well jest let me know. Thanks! :)

Comment: That's what I understood from the beginning, on the server you can directly store the binary stream received from the sender then you can directly send this stream to the receiver on request. I will try to post an answer to with sample.